# Find missing number with variable range for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to use VBA to show me numbers in the range 1-3 (integers only) that are missing from a variable range of rows.

Column D can be blank, or have a single digit number (1, 2 or 3).
Column E has numbers in decreasing value. Lowest value is 1.

The range is dependent on the value in column E.

Examples/explanation:

- E2 = 4, therefore it has to look for the missing numbers in D2-D5. These 4 rows have all three numbers.
- E6 = 2. Look for missing number in D6-D7. The missing number is 3.
- E8 = 1, **and** E8 is blank. Missing number 1, 2, 3
- (not in the table) A value in the E column could also be 1, and have a number 1-3 in the corresponding D column.

I think it might make it easier if I add a blank row between each grouped set of rows (between alternating colors in the image below). But I still probably need heaps of help, for this.

[image]

I really hope someone here is able to assist/understand what I'm trying to do. This is the last step of my code, and I'm dumbfounded as to how to make this work.

Comment: You can use `INDEX` to create a dynamically-sized Range that has the number of Rows that you want to check  (e.g. `INDEX(D2, 1, 0, E2, 1)`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Chronocidal, but I don't quite understand how to make it work. Index only has four arguments? I also added a table in the original post with "desired" result from the code. Column F shows the missing numbers.

Comment: sorry, got `INDEX` and `OFFSET` mixed up there - `OFFSET(D2,1,0,E2,1)`, and combine it with a `COUNTIF`

Comment: I am starting to realize I am probably in over my head. Started learning VBA a week and a half ago for this project. So far I've mostly copied/pasted code found elsewhere, as well as utilizing "record macro" at every opportunity. Maybe I need to take a step back, and start to learn the fundamentals. Just so frustrating that there's only one piece that's missing to complete my code.

Comment: I was trying a brute-force approach (Check for `1`, if it is missing then return `", 1", do the same for `2` and `3`, then combine them into 1 string and take the `MID(<string>, 3, 99)` to remove the first `", "`), but I could not get from your *explanation* to your *expected result* (I had `2` for the second row, and `1,2` for the third row, but you have those both blank?),  I think breaking it down to a step-by-step method would help you to think it through.

Comment: I changed my original post quite a bit. I've color-coded the cells that "belong" together. d2-d5 contains 1, 2 and 3, so there are no missing numbers. d5-d6 contains 1 and 2, so 3 is missing, and so on. I hope that this can help clarify what I need the code to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute-force method:  (Formula written for cell `F1`)

```
=IF(E1<IFERROR(OFFSET(E1,-1,0),-1),"",MID(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D1,0,0,E1,1),1)>0,"",", 1") & IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D1,0,0,E1,1),2)>0,"",", 2") & IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D1,0,0,E1,1),3)>0,"",", 3"),3,99))
```

Breaking it down:

> `=IF(E1<IFERROR(OFFSET(E1,-1,0),-1),"", <OUTPUT>)`
>   If the value in Column E is smaller than the value above it, show nothing.  Otherwise, show our `<OUTPUT>`

The next bits I will show in **reverse order**, as it will make more sense:

> `OFFSET(D1, 0, 0, E1, 1)`
>   This is a `<RANGE>` of cell, 1 cell wide and `E1` cells high, starting in `D1` (0 rows and 0 columns away)

Work out which numbers are missing from our `<RANGE>`, and what `<TEXT>` to show:

> `IF(COUNTIF(<RANGE>,1)>0,"",", 1") &`
>   If the number `1` does not appear in the Range, include `", 1"` in the `<TEXT>`
>   `IF(COUNTIF(<RANGE>,2)>0,"",", 2") &`
>   If the number `2` does not appear in the Range, include `", 2"` in the `<TEXT>`
>   `IF(COUNTIF(<RANGE>,3)>0,"",", 3")`
>   If the number `3` does not appear in the Range, include `", 3"` in the `<TEXT>`
>   This gives us a `<TEXT>` of `""`, `", 1"`, `", 1, 2"`, `", 1, 2, 3"`, `", 1, 3"`, `", 2"`, `", 2, 3"` or `", 3"`

Finally, tidy up our `<OUTPUT>`:

> `MID(<TEXT>, 3, 99)`
>   Trims the first 2 characters off the front of the `<TEXT>`

Comment: Wow, truly blown away at that response! Thank you so much! I won't have a chance to try it out until Monday, but it looks promising! Will probably have to come back to this several times to fully understand it. I hit the up-arrow, will hit "solve" when I've had a chance to try it out! Again, thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm, very grateful for the help you've provided! May I ask how long it took you to figure this out this solution? This type of programming is very foreign to me, so I can't really even give an educated guess on time-usage!

Comment: @Kenny Deciding on the initial approach probably took about 5 minutes?  You had already confirmed that there were only 3 option (`1`, `2` and `3`), so the individual checks were doable - for *big* lists you would need the Office365 `CONCAT` or `TEXTJOIN` functions.  The main thing there was how to only include commas *between* values, but fortunately I'd already used `MID` to drop initial characters like that before.

Comment: Hit a brief stumbling block when my output didn't match yours, but that was because I was doing *every* line.  Once you updated the image, I realised I needed the outer `IF` statement to make sure it was only the "maximum" lines.  Testing that I hit a bug on Row 1, since there was **no** cell above to compare with, but immediately rolled over to using `IFERROR` and `OFFSET` for that.  Call that another 2 minutes, (~7 total?) - and then 10 minutes to break it down, type it up and hopefully make sure it was all understandable!

Comment: A *lot* of it benefited from having worked on other things in the past that were *just* similar enough that I had "partial solutions" rattling around in memory, and it was just a case of breaking the requirements down step-by-step, then slotting the right bits together and polishing it up.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple UDF**

Assuming your first data block includes row 2 to 5, you could enter the following formula into cell `F2` e.g. `=ABSENT(D2:D5)` or even `=ABSENT(D2:E5)` to display the wanted result string in column F (which would be empty in the first case due to OP).

**Example code**

```
Function absent$(rng As Range)
Dim i&, s$, tmp, found                                          ' declare data types (Long, String, Variant, Variant)
For i = 1 To 3
    tmp = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(rng, 0, 1))   ' change 1st column to flat array
    found = Application.Match(i, tmp, 0)                        ' match numbers 1 to 3
    If IsError(found) Then                                      ' remember, if no match in array
       s = s & i & IIf(i < 3, ",", "")                          ' add absent number to string
    End If
Next i
absent = s                                                      ' return string
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, sadly the data is always changing, but it wouldn't be a problem just hard-coding in three rows containing the numbers 1 2 and 3 at the top of the data block, to make your suggestion work permanently. I will probably stick to the other solution provided, as it already works without any issues. But I will for sure play around with yours as well, as it's more in line with the type of programming I'm used to, so I'm sure it'll be helpful in the future!